# How to get frame id of iframe for using at executeScript chrome extension mv3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I study chrome extension **MV3** not **MV2**

I want to get frame id(integer) by frame id tag(string), not `all_frames: True` to use at `chrome.scripting.executeScript`

Because if there are many iframes, the code can be applied where I don't intend to.

For example, I want to inject javascript code only at iframe of **da_iframe_time** at this site [www.naver.com](https://www.naver.com/)

[image: naver site picture]

I wrote the code below based on the reference, but I don't know how to find the frame id using id tag.

> background.js(serviceworker)

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({tabId: tab.tabId}, function(res){
        // I want to use the id tag here to find the frame id I want.
        for(let idx=0; idx<res.length; idx++){
            console.log(res[idx].frameId);
        }
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tab.tabId, frameIds: [""]},
            files: ['injectCode.js']
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roads are two.
If you know the frame URL on which you want to inject, you could scan trought frames until you'll find out your desided one.
If you don't know the url, you should inject in all frames and write a content script which sleeps in all frames but works in your desided one.
This could be achieved by checking a specific DOM node that you know is unique among all frames.

Comment: How can I specify the frame using the id tag of iframe as shown in the code below? `let inner_iframe = document.getElementById('cafe_main').contentWindow;` Frame url is not stable because it always changes. And If use the method of searching for a URL with a particular word, frame I don't want may include that word.

Comment: And what do you mean specifically by checking a specific DOM node? There is no way to access the DOM node by frame itself.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you would like to do.
Is there only one site on which you'd run your content script or is there more than one with different layout characteristics?
In your question you indicate your intention to inject in the frame "da_iframe_time" on the site www.naver.com.
Do you always want to inject into a frame with that id?
Do you want to inject into one or more frames that have an id that contains a certain word?
Do you want to inject into one or more frames that have an SRC that contains a certain pattern? Please edit your question.

Comment: I want to inject only into one frame(**cafe_main**) at only one site([link](https://cafe.naver.com/joonggonara)). My extension full code is [link](https://github.com/DoTheBestMayB/RabbitCountry). And iframe url is  [link](https://cafe.naver.com/joonggonara?iframe_url=/ArticleList.nhn%3Fsearch.clubid=10050146%26search.menuid=339%26search.boardtype=L)

Comment: At background.js, this checks if the frame contains a specific word in url and modified them to inject only at specific iframes. But I wonder if there is a cleaner way than this. And service worker repeatedly inject the script 5 times.

Comment: I push github code for testing. 1. click extension  2. click button( 업자 지우기! ) 3. go site [link](https://cafe.naver.com/joonggonara) 4. click menu (휴대폰 판매/매입) 5. works // but service worker inject script code 5 times. And I want to inject script code only to **cafe_main**

Answer (score 0):

I've modified just a bit these 2 files.
As you can see I've turn the outer listener into "chrome.tabs.onUpdated"
and I've added a further condition in the block where you populate the frame array (just to avoid the main frame #0).

In handleExtension.js I've moved "sendMessage" to storage.local.set callback function 'cause you could risk send before the storage items has been set.

```
//in background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        let includeStr = "cafe";
        let notIncludeStr = "ArticleList";
        let file_name = "";
        chrome.storage.local.get(['eraseCheckBox'], async function(data) {
            var res = await chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({'tabId': tabId});
            var frames = [];
            for (let idx = 0; idx < res.length; idx++) {
                file_name = data.eraseCheckBox ? "eraseDealer" : "recoverDealer" + ".js";
                if (res[idx].url.includes(includeStr) && !res[idx].url.includes(notIncludeStr) && res[idx].frameId != 0) {
                    console.log(res[idx].url);
                    console.log("Do and Id: " + res[idx].frameId);
                    frames.push(res[idx].frameId);
                }
            }

            if (frames && file_name !== "") {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: {'tabId': tabId, frameIds: frames},
                    files: [file_name]
                });
            }       
        });
    }
});

//in handleExtension.js
document.getElementById('eraseButton').addEventListener("change", function() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        'eraseCheckBox': this.checked
    }, _ => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "recoverDo"})
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Error( Error in invocation of webNavigation.getAllFrames(object details, function callback): No matching signature ) occurs at `var res = await chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({'tabId': tabId});` It appears that webNavigation does not return promise although at reference webNavigation without callback function return promise

Comment: ok I tested with Chrome Canary Channel.  Try to convert promise in callback (as it was before).

Comment: After that, chrome extension inject code only once. But script not working after iframe refreshed by click href in iframe? For example, the site I mentioned is a Korean version of reddit. There are posts in the iframe that I want to access. And if press the number below to turn over the list of posts, the iframe node seems to refresh. In the process of refreshing, whether the script code that was inserted also disappears? So the injected code does not work. If I erase `res[idx].frameId != 0`( to avoid the main frame #0 ), it works as I expected.

Comment: 1. So, executeScript is entered normally only once, but each time the iframe button is pressed, the code is inserted again because tab is updated through iframe refreshed? Is this the right way? 2. When developing this extension, I made it thinking about Adblock. The extension I wrote is the way the code is injected, so I blink once before the post disappears. Is there a way not to blink like Adblock? I've been searching with 'Adblock', 'blink' keywords for the past few months, but I can't find the principles.

Comment: I commit the code to GitHub by referring to your code and advice .

Comment: By clicking as you previously suggested on 휴대폰 판매 / 매입
the frame content changes but the content script remains tied to the page.
if you want to monitor the changes inside the frame once the script is injected, you have to use mutationObserver to track the changes and reactivate the content script.

Comment: It's dawn in Korea, so I'll study what you said tomorrow and apply it. Thank you for your detailed help.

Comment: Writing:   if document.getElementById('cafe_main') !== null  in your content scripts means that you've designed your content scripts to be injected in frame #0.  So why asking all these problems? Inject in the zero frame and bye bye. Do not you think?

Comment: I implemented what you said to work in MV2. However, I am changing logic to implement the questions I asked while moving to MV3. I couldn't think of that part because I was only thinking about implementing service worker. I'm going to delete the part you mentioned and change it to function as a mutation overserver.

Comment: Before committing to GitHub, I erased that part and tested the modified code. However, when iframe is refreshed, the injected code does not work is the same.

Comment: I remembered why I wrote the code like that. I didn't know how to specify the frame at that time, so I wrote it down like that way. Because when I insert the code into an iframe without cafe_main, I wanted to make sure that the error code that iframe does not exist does not appear in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234050/discussion-between-4rigener-and-robbi).